# Nested loop with conditional list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have 2 lists

`l1 = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]`
`l2 = [['b',2,10],['c',3,8]]`

I want the below code to be replicated using list comprehension in python:

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    cnt = 0
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        if (l1[i][0]==l2[j][0]) & (l1[i][1]==l2[j][1]):
            cnt = 1
    if cnt==1:
        isintb.append(1)
    else:
        isintb.append(0)
```

expected output: [0,1,1]

can you guys help??

I tried as below:

`[[1 if (l1[i][0]==l2[j][0]) & (l1[i][1]==l2[j][1]) else 0 for j in range(len(l2))] for i in range(len(l1))]`

got output as below:
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]]

Comment: Are you sure you want to make your code more obfuscated by using a list comprehension? Generally, what you're asking is bad coding practice. Hint: if it's hard to implement a list comprehension then don't.

Comment: Replace logical *&* with *and* to make your code work as expected

Comment: even replacing & with and won't make it work, unless the conditionals are put inside the loop, and cnt is set back to 0 at each iteration.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Actually it does make it work with those data albeit a nonsensical approach

Comment: If you are always looking over the first two elements of the 2nd list, it might make it more clear to first make a list of only the first two items in `l2`. It would then look like `[1 if it in [l[:2] for l in l2] else 0 for it in l1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the inner for actually check if there is any match you can use `any` in the list comprehensions and cast the `bool` to `int`

```
isintb = [int(any((l1[i][0] == l2[j][0]) & (l1[i][1] == l2[j][1]) for j in range(len(l2)))) for i in range(len(l1))]
# [0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Replace logical & with and to make your code work as expected

Comment: @TheMyth Did you try running it? it does work as expected. Do you know what is the difference between those two?

Comment: maybe, but you're doing a binary `&` over boolean values, so might as well use the boolean operator...

Comment: @Guy It's not about difference, but about simply syntaxes?

Answer (score 0):

There you go. You can try using `any()` of python to get the output.
`any()` basically checks if even one value is true in the iterable.

```
isintb = [int(any([1 if (l1[i][0]==l2[j][0]) and (l1[i][1]==l2[j][1]) else 0 for j in range(len(l2))])) for i in range(len(l1))]
```

You are required to convert the `boolean` into `int` since you want outputs of `0` or `1`.

Docs:
[any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more obvious to anyone who has to maintain your code if you just used a double loop. List comprehensions have their place. This isn't the place.

Something like this:

```
l1 = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
l2 = [['b', 2, 10], ['c', 3, 8]]

isintb = []

for a, b in l1:
    for x, y, _ in l2:
        if a == x and b == y:
            isintb.append(1)
            break
    else:
        isintb.append(0)

print(isintb)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying a little by not using indices, and binary `&`:

```
print([int(any(i[0] == j[0] and i[1] == j[1] for j in l2))
           for i in l1])
```

or even shorter:

```
print([int(any(i == j[:2] for j in l2)) for i in l1])
```

If you can change your input to lists of tuples:

```
l1 = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)] 
l2 = [('b',2,10),('c',3,8)]
```

then this might be faster:

```
match = {j[:2] for j in l2}
print([int(i in match) for i in l1])
```